# AWS SES SMTP email works. AWS SES API does not send email

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES on a website with shared hosting platform (not on AWS)

When I send emails using the SMTP it works perfectly. When I attempt to call and use the API, no email is sent, no error message is received.

There are two reasons I want to use the API instead of SMTP
1) According to Amazon, the API is faster. 
2) One of my transactional emails is a reminder to clients to log in, and/or pay their account. SMTP cannot send email to more than 50 (if I am not mistaken). For that reason, I need to call the SendRawEmail.

Please help me with my code to send the email and to implement SendRawEmail

Here is my code:
    require ('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;


// Create an SesClient. Change the value of the region parameter if you're 
// using an AWS Region other than US West (Oregon). Change the value of the
// profile parameter if you want to use a profile in your credentials file
// other than the default.
$SesClient = new SesClient([
'profile' => 'default',
'version' => '2010-12-01',
'region'  => 'eu-central-1'
]);

// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
$sender_email = 'info@mydomain.com';

// Replace these sample addresses with the addresses of your recipients. If
// your account is still in the sandbox, these addresses must be verified.
$recipient_emails = ['info@example.com'];

// Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
// set, comment the following variable, and the
// 'ConfigurationSetName' => $configuration_set argument below.
//$configuration_set = 'ConfigSet';

$subject = 'Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for PHP)';
$plaintext_body = 'This email was sent with Amazon SES using the AWS SDK for PHP.' ;
$html_body =  '<h1>AWS Amazon Simple Email Service Test Email</h1>'.
          '<p>This email was sent with <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/ses/">'.
          'Amazon SES</a> using the <a href="https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/">'.
          'AWS SDK for PHP</a>.</p>';
$char_set = 'UTF-8';

try {
$result = $SesClient->sendEmail([
    'Destination' => [
        'ToAddresses' => $recipient_emails,
    ],
    'ReplyToAddresses' => [$sender_email],
    'Source' => $sender_email,
    'Message' => [
      'Body' => [
          'Html' => [
              'Charset' => $char_set,
              'Data' => $html_body,
          ],
          'Text' => [
              'Charset' => $char_set,
              'Data' => $plaintext_body,
          ],
      ],
      'Subject' => [
          'Charset' => $char_set,
          'Data' => $subject,
      ],
    ],
    // If you aren't using a configuration set, comment or delete the
    // following line
    'ConfigurationSetName' => $configuration_set,
]);
$messageId = $result['MessageId'];
echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");
} catch (AwsException $e) {
// output error message if fails
echo $e->getMessage();
echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ".$e->getAwsErrorMessage()."\n");
echo "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: *"no email is sent, no error message is received."*  But what is logged by `echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");`?

Comment: Nothing is logged. Blank screen.

Comment: So *that* is the actual problem you need to solve.  I'm not really a PHP expert, but according to your code, it seems impossible that nothing is displayed unless maybe an overall PHP execution timeout is firing that stops execution before that point is reached, and is masking the actual error. Perhaps there's an error log entry on your server?

Comment: Are You sure that You are using the correct credentials? The one used for the SMTP and for the  SES API are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error log. I had the same issue:

`require 'AWS/aws-autoloader.php';`

For other SDK uses (such as API calls) you may need to create a `.aws` folder to include `credentials`